# W3C geolocation, Error:position unavailable

Tags: javascript, geolocation, w3c-geolocation

I'm trying to implement the W3C geolocation API, even though I give the browser permission regarding my location I get error 2 (Position unavailable) while using it from Firefox, and I get error 1 (Permission denied) while trying it from chrome. The following is my code:

HTML button which calls the JS function:

Now we are going to talk about the Geolocation API

```
<input type="button" name="canbutt" value="draw c" onClick="javascript:geo()"/>
```

And my JS code:

```
         function geo(){

                    if (navigator.geolocation) {

                            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                                displayPosition, 
                                displayError);
                    }
                else {
                        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser");
                    }

        function displayPosition(position) {
                alert("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + ", Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
                        }
        function displayError(error) {
                var errors = { 
                    1: 'Permission denied',
                    2: 'Position unavailable',
                    3: 'Request timeout'
                    };
                alert("Error: " + errors[error.code]);
                    }


    }

     function canvas() {
                var canvas = document.getElementById("canv");
                var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                context.fillStyle="red";
                context.strokeStyle="blue";
                context.strokeRect(50,25,50,60);
                context.fillRect(50,25,50,60);
                context.strokeStyle="green";
                context.moveTo(0,0);
                context.lineTo(300,150);
                context.stroke();
                context.fillStyle="blue";
                context.font="bold 12px Arial";
                context.textAlign="start";
                context.fillText("This is some Text",50,110);
                var gradient=context.createLinearGradient(0,0,100,100);
                gradient.addColorStop(0,"white");
                gradient.addColorStop(1,"black");
                context.fillStyle=gradient;
                context.fillRect(50,50,100,100);
                context.fillText("Im using Gradient!",60,10);
                context.drawImage(image, 20,20);


                    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are restrictions in using Geolocation from `file:/// URI`. Try uploading your page on a web server (local server also works).